# padding a .dat file with zeros in python

Tags: python, append, padding

I have a `.dat` file (contains data of multiple datatypes). The end position of the data in the file is  `3183` and I want to pad the file with **zeros** till the end position count size becomes `9153`. How can I do this using python ? Please help.

The code that I have used till now is as below:

```
   datContent = open("DW_AMED.dat","r").readline()
   filesize = len(datContent)
   size = (filesize-1)
   print (size)
```

Its giving the output: **3183**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is *too broad*. Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: try `f.write(bytearray(9153-3183))`

Answer (score 0):

- Find the length of the file(FILE_SIZE) using [stat command](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stat.html)
- Open the  file in append mode
- Write to file number of bytes = *9153 - FILE_SIZE*